# how to select mysql one row inside another multi rows

Tags: mysql

```
$sql="select user,(select * from product where u_id in (select u_id from user)) from user";
```

I want to get every row under the relevant data rows in the product table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use limit.

```
select user,(select * from product where u_id in (select u_id from user) limit 1) from user;
```

But make sure that the only one row that you are going to fetch is the desired one. Adding more filters might help.